# CSS centering the bounding box for a set of absolute-positionned divs

Tags: css, css-position, centering

I don't know if this can be done with CSS, but before going the JavaScript way, I would like to know if it's possible to center (as a whole) a set of absolute positionned divs:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="item1" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top=50px>...some content...</div>
  <div id="item2" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top=0px>...some content...</div>
  <div id="item3" style="position:absolute;left:150px;top=100px>...some content...</div>
  <div id="item4" style="position:absolute;left:75px;top=75px>...some content...</div>
</div>
```

I would like to center the *bounding box* of those items in the page.

Of course since they're styled with "position:absolute", they're out of the flow, so the container div has a size of 0 px... and the usual tricks didn't work.

Finally, the snippet above being just *illustrative*, in practice ***the items would be arbitrarily positionned*** (some of them dynamically), and ***their size and content is not known*** (and can be dynamic too). Because of all this dynamicity, I would prefer to have everything handled by CSS is possible, rather than having hook a whole bunch of events.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can change your html and css than u can easily as like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="item1">...some content...</div>
  <div id="item2">...some content...</div>
  <div id="item3">...some content...</div>
  <div id="item4">...some content...</div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
#container{
background:red;

  overflow:hidden;
}
#item1, #item2, #item3, #item4{
background:pink;
  margin:10px;
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://tinkerbin.com/GsRHTqzh)

Comment: This is not centered and the container doesn't fit the content.

Comment: @EricGrange Give to item padding left according to your layout

Comment: What do you mean? In your CSS the values are fixed sizes, in my case the items size and positions are not known (and can be dynamic), so the bounding box is not known and dynamic too.

Answer (score 0):

How about to give a fix width to #container and giving a position:relative;
Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/65vk2/

Comment: Width and position of the items are not fixed, and as a consequence neither is that of the bounding box.